# Find duplicates in column combo

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I need to keep unique records among 2 columns.
Imagine in the dataframe (df) below, I want to delete the repeated info in columns x and y.

> x  y z
>
> 1  3 1
>
> 4  4 3
>
> 2  4 3
>
> 1  3 2
>
> 3  5 2

What I've done was to concatenate the XY= str(x)+str(y)and kept the unique values by pd.unique(df.XY()).
The record (1 3 1) and (1 3 2) would be duplicates.

I believe there has got to be a better way of doing this... Particularly as it comes to 3 or more columns.
Thanks,
MB

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x','y'])` should work, do you want to keep the first duplicate or remove it? if the latter then you'd need `keep=False` as an addtional param

Comment: There are quite a few related questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pandas+remove+duplicates

Comment: Thanks, I was over flooded with single column duplicates... I had issues with the wording while browsing questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x','y'])
   x  y  z
0  1  3  1
1  4  4  3
2  2  4  3
4  3  5  2
```

You can keep `first` or `last` duplicated rows with parameter `keep`:

```
print df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x','y'])
#it is same as:
print df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x','y'], keep='first')
   x  y  z
0  1  3  1
1  4  4  3
2  2  4  3
4  3  5  2

print df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x','y'], keep='last')
   x  y  z
1  4  4  3
2  2  4  3
3  1  3  2
4  3  5  2
```

If you need remove all duplicates, use `keep=False`:

```
print df.drop_duplicates(subset=['x','y'], keep=False)
   x  y  z
1  4  4  3
2  2  4  3
4  3  5  2
```